# String or binary data would be truncated on nChar type, how to take out phone number formatting

Tags: t-sql

I get an error that string or binary data would be truncated on line 14 which is the line that declares the table. The phone Number is nchar 10 and the number has phone formatting. I think I need take out the phone number formatting (927)968-7544. How would I do that?

```
declare @NextIdentityID table (PersonId int, People_ID int);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PeopleTest]
           ([People_ID]
           ,[text])
           output Inserted.People_ID, Inserted.PersonId into @NextIdentityID(People_ID, PersonId)
     SELECT
           PEOPLE_ID,'row1' --PEOPLE_ID, 000092437
           FROM         PeopleChanges
           WHERE PEOPLE_ID = '000092435' --just insert our single test row
select * from @NextIdentityID           
/*
PersonId    People_ID
377 92435
*/
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Phone] --Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 14, String or binary data would be truncated.
           ([PersonPhoneId] --000092437
           ,[PersonId] --PersonId int 361
           ,[PhoneType] --'Home Row 1'
           ,[Number]) --(927)968-7544, NULL, (214)709-3001

--needs to be PEOPLE_ID, PersonId, (Type, Home, Office, Cell), Phone1/Phone2/Phone3
select PC.PEOPLE_ID, Idn.PersonId,'Home Row 1', PC.Phone1 from @NextIdentityID Idn INNER JOIN PEOPLECHANGES PC on Idn.People_ID = CONVERT(INT, PC.People_ID) --PEOPLE_ID 000092437, PersonID 92437 one is varchar, one is integer
union all select PC.PEOPLE_ID, Idn.PersonId,'Office Row 2', PC.Phone2 from @NextIdentityID Idn INNER JOIN PEOPLECHANGES PC on Idn.People_ID = CONVERT(INT, PC.People_ID)
union all select PC.PEOPLE_ID, Idn.PersonId,'Cell Row 3', PC.Phone3 from @NextIdentityID Idn INNER JOIN PEOPLECHANGES PC on Idn.People_ID = CONVERT(INT, PC.People_ID)
/*
PEOPLE_ID   PersonId    (No column name)    Phone1
000092435   380 Home Row 1  (927)968-7544
000092435   380 Office Row 2    NULL
000092435   380 Cell Row 3  (214)709-3001

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phone](
    [PersonPhoneId] [int] NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhoneType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Number] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
*/
```

Comment: How about just turning [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) loose thrice to change "(", ")" and "-" to empty strings? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. I've assumed SQL Server.

Comment: it has the tsql tag, it's sql server 2008r

Comment: `tsql` tag: "T-SQL (Transact Structured Query Language) is the extension of SQL functionality supported by Sybase ASE and Microsoft SQL Server. ..." Now we know it isn't Sybase ASE, and have a version to boot. How far did you get with `Replace()`?

Comment: this one seems to work REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PC.Phone1,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one seems to work REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PC.Phone1,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','')

Answer (score 0):

String or binary data would be truncated :

this error message will appears when there is no enough space in destination table. here with your example column [Number] having nchar. but you are supplying values with length more than 10

if you increase column length by 13 you will overcome from your error

```
ALter Table Phone alter column Number Nchar(13)
```

Comment: the table is a third party vendor so i can't change the column, i was able to take out the -()